# I keep getting the DPC_Watchdog_Violation BSoD and I don't know how to fix it. (Windows 10)

Tags: windows-10, drivers, bsod, crash, dpc

I keep getting the **DPC_Watchdog_Violation BSOD (Bugcheck: 133)**

#### I tried all of these solutions:

1. Updating Drivers
2. `chkdsk C: /f` in cmd
3. `chkdsk C: /r` in cmd
4. `sfc /scannow` in cmd
5. Resetting BIOS
6. Full system scan with Norton Antivirus
7. Full system scan with Malwarebytes
8. Removing recently installed software
9. Replacing the iastor.sys driver with the storachi.sys driver
10. Updates
    But none of them fixed the issue.

#### When and how does this happen:

This happens atleast twice a day. This occurs randomly. First, the pointer gets stuck and doesn't move. Then, even my keyboard stops working and the system freezes. After 10 to 30 seconds, the BSOD (DPC_Watchdog_Violation) appears, and then the laptop restarts. This is extremely annoying because it sometimes happens during online classes and unsaved files are lost.

### Minidump Files:

#### Minidump file for most recent BSoD:

```
Microsoft (R) Windows Debugger Version 10.0.20153.1000 AMD64
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.


Loading Dump File [C:\WINDOWS\MEMORY.DMP]
Kernel Bitmap Dump File: Kernel address space is available, User address space may not be available.


************* Path validation summary **************
Response                         Time (ms)     Location
Deferred                                       srv*
Symbol search path is: srv*
Executable search path is: 
Windows 10 Kernel Version 19041 MP (4 procs) Free x64
Product: WinNt, suite: TerminalServer SingleUserTS
Edition build lab: 19041.1.amd64fre.vb_release.191206-1406
Machine Name:
Kernel base = 0xfffff801`71800000 PsLoadedModuleList = 0xfffff801`7242a2b0
Debug session time: Thu Dec 10 08:04:34.079 2020 (UTC + 5:30)
System Uptime: 0 days 1:00:12.771
Loading Kernel Symbols
...............................................................
................................................................
................................................................
...................................
Loading User Symbols

Loading unloaded module list
.................
For analysis of this file, run !analyze -v
nt!KeBugCheckEx:
fffff801`71bf5780 48894c2408      mov     qword ptr [rsp+8],rcx ss:ffffc901`207fae20=0000000000000133
NatVis script unloaded from 'C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.WinDbg_1.2007.6001.0_neutral__8wekyb3d8bbwe\amd64\Visualizers\atlmfc.natvis'
NatVis script unloaded from 'C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.WinDbg_1.2007.6001.0_neutral__8wekyb3d8bbwe\amd64\Visualizers\concurrency.natvis'
NatVis script unloaded from 'C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.WinDbg_1.2007.6001.0_neutral__8wekyb3d8bbwe\amd64\Visualizers\cpp_rest.natvis'
NatVis script unloaded from 'C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.WinDbg_1.2007.6001.0_neutral__8wekyb3d8bbwe\amd64\Visualizers\Kernel.natvis'
NatVis script unloaded from 'C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.WinDbg_1.2007.6001.0_neutral__8wekyb3d8bbwe\amd64\Visualizers\stl.natvis'
NatVis script unloaded from 'C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.WinDbg_1.2007.6001.0_neutral__8wekyb3d8bbwe\amd64\Visualizers\Windows.Data.Json.natvis'
NatVis script unloaded from 'C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.WinDbg_1.2007.6001.0_neutral__8wekyb3d8bbwe\amd64\Visualizers\Windows.Devices.Geolocation.natvis'
NatVis script unloaded from 'C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.WinDbg_1.2007.6001.0_neutral__8wekyb3d8bbwe\amd64\Visualizers\Windows.Devices.Sensors.natvis'
NatVis script unloaded from 'C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.WinDbg_1.2007.6001.0_neutral__8wekyb3d8bbwe\amd64\Visualizers\Windows.Media.natvis'
NatVis script unloaded from 'C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.WinDbg_1.2007.6001.0_neutral__8wekyb3d8bbwe\amd64\Visualizers\windows.natvis'
NatVis script unloaded from 'C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.WinDbg_1.2007.6001.0_neutral__8wekyb3d8bbwe\amd64\Visualizers\winrt.natvis'

Microsoft (R) Windows Debugger Version 10.0.20153.1000 AMD64
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.


Loading Dump File [C:\Windows\Minidump\121020-47578-01.dmp]
Mini Kernel Dump File: Only registers and stack trace are available


************* Path validation summary **************
Response                         Time (ms)     Location
Deferred                                       srv*
Symbol search path is: srv*
Executable search path is: 
Windows 10 Kernel Version 19041 MP (4 procs) Free x64
Product: WinNt, suite: TerminalServer SingleUserTS
Edition build lab: 19041.1.amd64fre.vb_release.191206-1406
Machine Name:
Kernel base = 0xfffff801`71800000 PsLoadedModuleList = 0xfffff801`7242a2b0
Debug session time: Thu Dec 10 08:04:34.079 2020 (UTC + 5:30)
System Uptime: 0 days 1:00:12.771
Loading Kernel Symbols
...............................................................
................................................................
................................................................
...................................
Loading User Symbols
Loading unloaded module list
.................
For analysis of this file, run !analyze -v
nt!KeBugCheckEx:
fffff801`71bf5780 48894c2408      mov     qword ptr [rsp+8],rcx ss:ffffc901`207fae20=0000000000000133
1: kd> !analyze -v
*******************************************************************************
*                                                                             *
*                        Bugcheck Analysis                                    *
*                                                                             *
*******************************************************************************

DPC_WATCHDOG_VIOLATION (133)
The DPC watchdog detected a prolonged run time at an IRQL of DISPATCH_LEVEL
or above.
Arguments:
Arg1: 0000000000000001, The system cumulatively spent an extended period of time at
    DISPATCH_LEVEL or above. The offending component can usually be
    identified with a stack trace.
Arg2: 0000000000001e00, The watchdog period.
Arg3: fffff801724fa320, cast to nt!DPC_WATCHDOG_GLOBAL_TRIAGE_BLOCK, which contains
    additional information regarding the cumulative timeout
Arg4: 0000000000000000

Debugging Details:
------------------

*************************************************************************
***                                                                   ***
***                                                                   ***
***    Either you specified an unqualified symbol, or your debugger   ***
***    doesn't have full symbol information.  Unqualified symbol      ***
***    resolution is turned off by default. Please either specify a   ***
***    fully qualified symbol module!symbolname, or enable resolution ***
***    of unqualified symbols by typing ".symopt- 100". Note that     ***
***    enabling unqualified symbol resolution with network symbol     ***
***    server shares in the symbol path may cause the debugger to     ***
***    appear to hang for long periods of time when an incorrect      ***
***    symbol name is typed or the network symbol server is down.     ***
***                                                                   ***
***    For some commands to work properly, your symbol path           ***
***    must point to .pdb files that have full type information.      ***
***                                                                   ***
***    Certain .pdb files (such as the public OS symbols) do not      ***
***    contain the required information.  Contact the group that      ***
***    provided you with these symbols if you need this command to    ***
***    work.                                                          ***
***                                                                   ***
***    Type referenced: TickPeriods                                   ***
***                                                                   ***
*************************************************************************
*** WARNING: Unable to verify checksum for win32k.sys

KEY_VALUES_STRING: 1

    Key  : Analysis.CPU.mSec
    Value: 15655

    Key  : Analysis.DebugAnalysisProvider.CPP
    Value: Create: 8007007e on RKS2-PC

    Key  : Analysis.DebugData
    Value: CreateObject

    Key  : Analysis.DebugModel
    Value: CreateObject

    Key  : Analysis.Elapsed.mSec
    Value: 87650

    Key  : Analysis.Memory.CommitPeak.Mb
    Value: 99

    Key  : Analysis.System
    Value: CreateObject

    Key  : WER.OS.Branch
    Value: vb_release

    Key  : WER.OS.Timestamp
    Value: 2019-12-06T14:06:00Z

    Key  : WER.OS.Version
    Value: 10.0.19041.1


ADDITIONAL_XML: 1

OS_BUILD_LAYERS: 1

BUGCHECK_CODE:  133

BUGCHECK_P1: 1

BUGCHECK_P2: 1e00

BUGCHECK_P3: fffff801724fa320

BUGCHECK_P4: 0

DPC_TIMEOUT_TYPE:  DPC_QUEUE_EXECUTION_TIMEOUT_EXCEEDED

TRAP_FRAME:  ffff8b00cd9bd6e0 -- (.trap 0xffff8b00cd9bd6e0)
NOTE: The trap frame does not contain all registers.
Some register values may be zeroed or incorrect.
rax=0000000000000001 rbx=0000000000000000 rcx=ffffb68b1e018110
rdx=0000000000000000 rsi=0000000000000000 rdi=0000000000000000
rip=fffff80171ae47ff rsp=ffff8b00cd9bd870 rbp=ffffb68b19f8f050
 r8=0000000000000000  r9=0000000000000000 r10=0000000000000000
r11=fffff780000003b0 r12=0000000000000000 r13=0000000000000000
r14=0000000000000000 r15=0000000000000000
iopl=0         nv up ei pl nz na pe nc
nt!KxWaitForSpinLockAndAcquire+0x2f:
fffff801`71ae47ff 4885c0          test    rax,rax
Resetting default scope

BLACKBOXBSD: 1 (!blackboxbsd)


BLACKBOXNTFS: 1 (!blackboxntfs)


BLACKBOXPNP: 1 (!blackboxpnp)


BLACKBOXWINLOGON: 1

CUSTOMER_CRASH_COUNT:  1

PROCESS_NAME:  System

STACK_TEXT:  
ffffc901`207fae18 fffff801`71c3aa0c     : 00000000`00000133 00000000`00000001 00000000`00001e00 fffff801`724fa320 : nt!KeBugCheckEx
ffffc901`207fae20 fffff801`71a6f9a3     : 00000691`6c4902d8 ffffc901`207a8180 00000000`00000000 ffffc901`207a8180 : nt!KeAccumulateTicks+0x1c880c
ffffc901`207fae80 fffff801`71a6f48a     : ffffb68b`178ad480 ffff8b00`cd9bd760 fffff801`72524400 00000000`00000000 : nt!KeClockInterruptNotify+0x453
ffffc901`207faf30 fffff801`71b27ef5     : ffffb68b`178ad480 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 ffff82b1`544c3565 : nt!HalpTimerClockIpiRoutine+0x1a
ffffc901`207faf60 fffff801`71bf722a     : ffff8b00`cd9bd760 ffffb68b`178ad480 00000000`00000100 00000000`00000000 : nt!KiCallInterruptServiceRoutine+0xa5
ffffc901`207fafb0 fffff801`71bf7797     : 00000000`36923759 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : nt!KiInterruptSubDispatchNoLockNoEtw+0xfa
ffff8b00`cd9bd6e0 fffff801`71ae47ff     : ffff8b00`cd9bd898 656c646e`61682074 00000000`00000001 ffff8b00`cd9bd940 : nt!KiInterruptDispatchNoLockNoEtw+0x37
ffff8b00`cd9bd870 fffff801`71ae47c8     : ffffb68b`1e018110 ffffc901`207a8180 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : nt!KxWaitForSpinLockAndAcquire+0x2f
ffff8b00`cd9bd8a0 fffff801`7eb1c316     : ffffb68b`1e05b200 ffffb68b`1d1c6dd0 ffffb68b`1e065030 00000000`00000076 : nt!KeAcquireSpinLockRaiseToDpc+0x88
ffff8b00`cd9bd8d0 fffff801`7eb24eca     : ffffb68b`1e013030 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : athw8x!ath_bt_coex_rssi_update+0x7e
ffff8b00`cd9bd970 fffff801`7eaec502     : ffffb68b`1e013030 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 ffffffff`ffffffff : athw8x!ath_bt_coex_wlan_state_update+0x440a
ffff8b00`cd9bda00 fffff801`7eaec611     : ffffb68b`1e017270 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000100 fffff801`75719c50 : athw8x!ath_defer_callback_func+0x1a
ffff8b00`cd9bda30 fffff801`7ec9946b     : ffffb68b`1e017270 ffffb68b`1d1c6d60 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : athw8x!ath_schedule_defer_call+0x45
ffff8b00`cd9bda70 fffff801`75719c61     : ffffb68b`1d1c6d60 ffffb68b`1dea0b50 fffff801`75719c50 ffffb68b`17889ca0 : athw8x!MpCommonWorkitemRoutine+0x16b
ffff8b00`cd9bdad0 fffff801`71b5a435     : 00000000`00000000 ffffb68b`1d1c6dd0 ffffb68b`19f8f050 fffff801`74bbc5c0 : ndis!ndisDispatchIoWorkItem+0x11
ffff8b00`cd9bdb00 fffff801`71a25975     : ffffb68b`19302080 ffffb68b`19302080 fffff801`71b5a300 ffffb68b`00000000 : nt!IopProcessWorkItem+0x135
ffff8b00`cd9bdb70 fffff801`71b17e25     : ffffb68b`19302080 00000000`00000080 ffffb68b`1788c180 000fa425`bd9bbfff : nt!ExpWorkerThread+0x105
ffff8b00`cd9bdc10 fffff801`71bfcdd8     : ffffc901`207a8180 ffffb68b`19302080 fffff801`71b17dd0 00000000`00000000 : nt!PspSystemThreadStartup+0x55
ffff8b00`cd9bdc60 00000000`00000000     : ffff8b00`cd9be000 ffff8b00`cd9b8000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : nt!KiStartSystemThread+0x28


SYMBOL_NAME:  athw8x!ath_bt_coex_rssi_update+7e

MODULE_NAME: athw8x

IMAGE_NAME:  athw8x.sys

IMAGE_VERSION:  3.0.2.201

STACK_COMMAND:  .thread ; .cxr ; kb

BUCKET_ID_FUNC_OFFSET:  7e

FAILURE_BUCKET_ID:  0x133_ISR_athw8x!ath_bt_coex_rssi_update

OS_VERSION:  10.0.19041.1

BUILDLAB_STR:  vb_release

OSPLATFORM_TYPE:  x64

OSNAME:  Windows 10

FAILURE_ID_HASH:  {ba7d501e-3ea2-f0fc-5927-037942000957}

Followup:     MachineOwner
---------
```

#### Minidump file for 2nd most recent BSoD:

```
Microsoft (R) Windows Debugger Version 10.0.20153.1000 AMD64
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.


Loading Dump File [C:\Windows\Minidump\120920-44031-01.dmp]
Mini Kernel Dump File: Only registers and stack trace are available


************* Path validation summary **************
Response                         Time (ms)     Location
Deferred                                       srv*
Symbol search path is: srv*
Executable search path is: 
Windows 10 Kernel Version 19041 MP (4 procs) Free x64
Product: WinNt, suite: TerminalServer SingleUserTS
Edition build lab: 19041.1.amd64fre.vb_release.191206-1406
Machine Name:
Kernel base = 0xfffff801`63200000 PsLoadedModuleList = 0xfffff801`63e2a2b0
Debug session time: Wed Dec  9 18:09:48.194 2020 (UTC + 5:30)
System Uptime: 0 days 1:38:01.875
Loading Kernel Symbols
...............................................................
................................................................
................................................................
...................................
Loading User Symbols
Loading unloaded module list
.............
For analysis of this file, run !analyze -v
nt!KeBugCheckEx:
fffff801`635f5780 48894c2408      mov     qword ptr [rsp+8],rcx ss:0018:ffffb000`c35fae20=0000000000000133
1: kd> !analyze -v
*******************************************************************************
*                                                                             *
*                        Bugcheck Analysis                                    *
*                                                                             *
*******************************************************************************

DPC_WATCHDOG_VIOLATION (133)
The DPC watchdog detected a prolonged run time at an IRQL of DISPATCH_LEVEL
or above.
Arguments:
Arg1: 0000000000000001, The system cumulatively spent an extended period of time at
    DISPATCH_LEVEL or above. The offending component can usually be
    identified with a stack trace.
Arg2: 0000000000001e00, The watchdog period.
Arg3: fffff80163efa320, cast to nt!DPC_WATCHDOG_GLOBAL_TRIAGE_BLOCK, which contains
    additional information regarding the cumulative timeout
Arg4: 0000000000000000

Debugging Details:
------------------

*************************************************************************
***                                                                   ***
***                                                                   ***
***    Either you specified an unqualified symbol, or your debugger   ***
***    doesn't have full symbol information.  Unqualified symbol      ***
***    resolution is turned off by default. Please either specify a   ***
***    fully qualified symbol module!symbolname, or enable resolution ***
***    of unqualified symbols by typing ".symopt- 100". Note that     ***
***    enabling unqualified symbol resolution with network symbol     ***
***    server shares in the symbol path may cause the debugger to     ***
***    appear to hang for long periods of time when an incorrect      ***
***    symbol name is typed or the network symbol server is down.     ***
***                                                                   ***
***    For some commands to work properly, your symbol path           ***
***    must point to .pdb files that have full type information.      ***
***                                                                   ***
***    Certain .pdb files (such as the public OS symbols) do not      ***
***    contain the required information.  Contact the group that      ***
***    provided you with these symbols if you need this command to    ***
***    work.                                                          ***
***                                                                   ***
***    Type referenced: TickPeriods                                   ***
***                                                                   ***
*************************************************************************
*** WARNING: Unable to verify checksum for win32k.sys

KEY_VALUES_STRING: 1

    Key  : Analysis.CPU.mSec
    Value: 12718

    Key  : Analysis.DebugAnalysisProvider.CPP
    Value: Create: 8007007e on RKS2-PC

    Key  : Analysis.DebugData
    Value: CreateObject

    Key  : Analysis.DebugModel
    Value: CreateObject

    Key  : Analysis.Elapsed.mSec
    Value: 45968

    Key  : Analysis.Memory.CommitPeak.Mb
    Value: 100

    Key  : Analysis.System
    Value: CreateObject

    Key  : WER.OS.Branch
    Value: vb_release

    Key  : WER.OS.Timestamp
    Value: 2019-12-06T14:06:00Z

    Key  : WER.OS.Version
    Value: 10.0.19041.1


ADDITIONAL_XML: 1

OS_BUILD_LAYERS: 1

BUGCHECK_CODE:  133

BUGCHECK_P1: 1

BUGCHECK_P2: 1e00

BUGCHECK_P3: fffff80163efa320

BUGCHECK_P4: 0

DPC_TIMEOUT_TYPE:  DPC_QUEUE_EXECUTION_TIMEOUT_EXCEEDED

TRAP_FRAME:  ffffad001a5f16e0 -- (.trap 0xffffad001a5f16e0)
NOTE: The trap frame does not contain all registers.
Some register values may be zeroed or incorrect.
rax=0000000000000001 rbx=0000000000000000 rcx=ffff9c88fce63110
rdx=0000000000000000 rsi=0000000000000000 rdi=0000000000000000
rip=fffff801634e47f8 rsp=ffffad001a5f1870 rbp=ffff9c88fc040050
 r8=0000000000000000  r9=0000000000000000 r10=0000000000000000
r11=fffff780000003b0 r12=0000000000000000 r13=0000000000000000
r14=0000000000000000 r15=0000000000000000
iopl=0         nv up ei pl nz na pe nc
nt!KxWaitForSpinLockAndAcquire+0x28:
fffff801`634e47f8 7446            je      nt!KxWaitForSpinLockAndAcquire+0x70 (fffff801`634e4840) [br=0]
Resetting default scope

BLACKBOXBSD: 1 (!blackboxbsd)


BLACKBOXNTFS: 1 (!blackboxntfs)


BLACKBOXPNP: 1 (!blackboxpnp)


BLACKBOXWINLOGON: 1

CUSTOMER_CRASH_COUNT:  1

PROCESS_NAME:  System

STACK_TEXT:  
ffffb000`c35fae18 fffff801`6363aa0c     : 00000000`00000133 00000000`00000001 00000000`00001e00 fffff801`63efa320 : nt!KeBugCheckEx
ffffb000`c35fae20 fffff801`6346f9a3     : 00000aaf`93214cc4 ffffb000`c35a8180 00000000`00000000 ffffb000`c35a8180 : nt!KeAccumulateTicks+0x1c880c
ffffb000`c35fae80 fffff801`6346f48a     : ffff9c88`f76c3480 ffffad00`1a5f1760 fffff801`63f24400 00000000`00000000 : nt!KeClockInterruptNotify+0x453
ffffb000`c35faf30 fffff801`63527ef5     : ffff9c88`f76c3480 fffff801`635146b7 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : nt!HalpTimerClockIpiRoutine+0x1a
ffffb000`c35faf60 fffff801`635f722a     : ffffad00`1a5f1760 ffff9c88`f76c3480 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : nt!KiCallInterruptServiceRoutine+0xa5
ffffb000`c35fafb0 fffff801`635f7797     : 00000000`4d34f90a fffff801`635fc506 ffffad00`1a5f1860 00000000`00000100 : nt!KiInterruptSubDispatchNoLockNoEtw+0xfa
ffffad00`1a5f16e0 fffff801`634e47f8     : 6f6e2033`20746e65 656c646e`61682074 61747320`6e692064 20454c44`49206574 : nt!KiInterruptDispatchNoLockNoEtw+0x37
ffffad00`1a5f1870 fffff801`634e47c8     : ffff9c88`fce63110 ffffb000`c35a8180 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : nt!KxWaitForSpinLockAndAcquire+0x28
ffffad00`1a5f18a0 fffff801`7079c316     : ffff9c88`fcdad500 ffff9c88`fcdd91d0 ffff9c88`fce75030 00000000`00000076 : nt!KeAcquireSpinLockRaiseToDpc+0x88
ffffad00`1a5f18d0 fffff801`707a4eca     : ffff9c88`fce5e030 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : athw8x!ath_bt_coex_rssi_update+0x7e
ffffad00`1a5f1970 fffff801`7076c502     : ffff9c88`fce5e030 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 ffffffff`ffffffff : athw8x!ath_bt_coex_wlan_state_update+0x440a
ffffad00`1a5f1a00 fffff801`7076c611     : ffff9c88`fce62270 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 fffff801`66f09c50 : athw8x!ath_defer_callback_func+0x1a
ffffad00`1a5f1a30 fffff801`7091946b     : ffff9c88`fce62270 ffff9c88`fcdd7db0 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : athw8x!ath_schedule_defer_call+0x45
ffffad00`1a5f1a70 fffff801`66f09c61     : ffff9c88`fcdd7db0 ffff9c88`fcd563d0 fffff801`66f09c50 ffff9c88`f768a580 : athw8x!MpCommonWorkitemRoutine+0x16b
ffffad00`1a5f1ad0 fffff801`6355a435     : 00000000`00000000 ffff9c88`fcdd91d0 ffff9c88`fc040050 ffff9c88`f768f080 : ndis!ndisDispatchIoWorkItem+0x11
ffffad00`1a5f1b00 fffff801`63425975     : ffff9c88`fa044040 ffff9c88`fa044040 fffff801`6355a300 ffff9c88`00000000 : nt!IopProcessWorkItem+0x135
ffffad00`1a5f1b70 fffff801`63517e25     : ffff9c88`fa044040 00000000`00000080 ffff9c88`f7678040 000fa425`bd9bbfff : nt!ExpWorkerThread+0x105
ffffad00`1a5f1c10 fffff801`635fcdd8     : ffffb000`c35a8180 ffff9c88`fa044040 fffff801`63517dd0 00000000`00000000 : nt!PspSystemThreadStartup+0x55
ffffad00`1a5f1c60 00000000`00000000     : ffffad00`1a5f2000 ffffad00`1a5ec000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : nt!KiStartSystemThread+0x28


SYMBOL_NAME:  athw8x!ath_bt_coex_rssi_update+7e

MODULE_NAME: athw8x

IMAGE_NAME:  athw8x.sys

IMAGE_VERSION:  3.0.2.201

STACK_COMMAND:  .thread ; .cxr ; kb

BUCKET_ID_FUNC_OFFSET:  7e

FAILURE_BUCKET_ID:  0x133_ISR_athw8x!ath_bt_coex_rssi_update

OS_VERSION:  10.0.19041.1

BUILDLAB_STR:  vb_release

OSPLATFORM_TYPE:  x64

OSNAME:  Windows 10

FAILURE_ID_HASH:  {ba7d501e-3ea2-f0fc-5927-037942000957}

Followup:     MachineOwner
---------
```

Please help me fix this issue.

Comment: athw8x.sys is the network card driver. This is the one you need updating/reinstalling to fix the issue. It seems like this driver is corrupt. See also https://www.tenforums.com/bsod-crashes-debugging/41197-another-dpc-watchdog-violation-victim.html

Comment: Thank You so much for helping